how can we add the function return type in request object in nest js
i want to create a response format serialization for globally so i want to add the function return type in request object. so in the interceptor i can take the return type and apply the serialization. i want to apply the interceptor globally for all the module to commonaly used the global level. so thats why i want to add the function return type in request object
example
@Controller(':breedId/cats')
export class CatsController {
  constructor(
    private readonly CatsService: CatsService,
  ) {}

  @Post()
  @ReturnType(Dto)
   create(
    @Param('breedId', ParseIntPipe) breedId: number,
    @Body() dto: CreateDto,
  ): Promise<CreateDto> {
   return ...   
  }

  @Post('list')
  async findAll(
    @Param('breedId', ParseIntPipe) breedId: number,
    @Body() CreateDto: CreateDto,
  ): Promise<CreateDto[]>  {

   
    return ...;
  }



To send the response in the format chosen by the request, you can create an interceptor.  This interceptor reads the format from the request.query parameter (we get the request object from the context) and then applies the appropriate serialization function to the response to return the desired type.  Here's an example of the interceptor:
    import {
  Injectable,
  NestInterceptor,
  ExecutionContext,
  CallHandler,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

// Define a type to represent serialization formats
type SerializationFormat = 'json' | 'xml' | 'simple';

@Injectable()
export class ResponseSerializationInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const format = this.getFormat(request); // Get format from request

    return next.handle().pipe(
      map((data) => {
        if (format) {
          switch (format) {
            case 'json':
              return this.toJson(data);
            case 'xml':
              return this.toXml(data);
            case 'simple':
              return 'Simple data';
            default:
              return data;
          }
        } else {
          return data;
        }
      }),
    );
  }

  private getFormat(request: any): SerializationFormat | undefined {
    console.log(request.query.format);
    const format = request.query.format;

    return format;
  }

  private toJson(data) {
    return { data, type: 'json' };
  }
  
  private toXml(data) {
    return { data, type: 'xml' };
  }
}

and to apply the intertecptor on all module, we simply declare it in the main.ts file :
app.useGlobalInterceptors(new ResponseSerializationInterceptor());

